# Running Thor Task from Migration

Tags: ruby, rake, invoke, thor

I want to call a thor task from a Migration.
With rake I can write

```
def self.up
  Rake::Task["db:rollback"].invoke
end
```

But how can i do this with thor?
(The thor command is "thor db:rollback")
(`thor db:rollback` is not a option, I want so see the output and the script should abort on errors)

UPDATE:
The migration is called from the Thorfile

It looks like this:

```
require 'active_record'
class Db < Thor
  desc "migrate", "description ..."
  def migrate
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(MIGRATIONS_PATH)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `db:rollback` refers to the `rollback` task of the `Db` class, then you can do this:

```
script = Db.new
script.invoke(:rollback)
```

You can read more in the docs: http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Base/ClassMethods#start-instance_method

Comment: When the migration is executed a error is raised by DB.new.
"uninitialized constant CreateUsers::Db".
It seems like it tries to find the Db thor class in the migration itself.
(I updated my question)

Comment: Make sure that the class is loaded, and make sure you use the right capitalization. `Db` is not the same as `DB`, and vice versa. My answer was for the general case of how to invoke Thor tasks, not your specific case, so make sure you have the names right and that the class you want to use is loaded.